# there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#

I am getting a error while mapping a result set of a procedure, not able to figure out the exact solution for that.Can someone please help me do so.

Code what I am using:`DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth.Value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfBirth.Value),`

Datatype for DateofBirth is DateTime.

And error what i am getting is"**Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'System.DateTime'**"

Comment: because 0 is not a date

Comment: What you want to assign to `DateOfBirth` if `DateOfBirth.Value==null`?, `0` is not assignable since it is of type integer. you have to assign some DateTime object, Something like `DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: Are you assigning `DateOfBirth` to itself? There is no need for `Convert.ToDateTime` in that case! If the type is `DateTime?`, i.e. a nullable DateTime, you do not use `.Value == null`. Retrieving `.Value` will explode with an `InvalidOperationException` if the nullable value is null. It is not clear what you want. If you use `DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth.GetValueOrDefault();`, you assign the property to itself, but change a possible null value into 1 January 0001.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conversion from `0` to `DateTime`. So the type of the result of the `?:` operator cannot be determined. It will be `int` in one case and `DateTime` in the other one. That's what the compiler tells you in its error message.

If you really want to get rid of the `null` entries, use a valid `DateTime` value (e.g. `DateTime.MinValue`) as a fallback instead.

Also, you may want to use the `??` operator:

```
DateTime? DateOfBirth = //... can be null or not
DateTime myDateOfBirth = DateOfBirth ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Of course, `null` may be a better representation for a missing value...

Answer (score 0):

This code says:

If DateOfBirth.Value is NULL Then
  DateOfBirth = integer zero
Else
  DateOfBirth = Convert DateOfBirth to DateTime

So, if DateOfBirth is null in the beginning, you are trying to set it to an integer zero, which is not good

Answer (score -2):

If u try to compare DateTime. Try to convert into something like this

```
 DateTime DateofBirth = DateTime.Now;


 if (DateofBirth .ToString() == null || DateofBirth .ToString() ==string.Empty)
      { 
       // do something
      }
```

You cant compare it into INT but you can compare it to string

Comment: The `.ToString()` implementation of `DateTime` never returns `null` or `""`, so I shall downvote. The `.ToString()` of `Nullable<>` may return `""`, but that is not something you would normally utilize in a check.